# Alphabetic order in loop

Tags: php

I've got this code:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'html')
    {   

        $patterns = array();
        $patterns[0] = '/_/';
        $patterns[1] = '/.html/';
        $patterns[2] = '/index/';
        $replacements = array();
        $replacements[2] = ' ';
        $replacements[1] = '';
        $replacements[0] = 'Strona główna';
        $wynik = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $file);

        $newVariable = str_replace("_", " ", $file);  
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.ucfirst($wynik).'</a></li>';
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
<P>List of files:</p>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
```

Is there a way to display the list of files in alphabetic order? Now the script lists html files in the directory where it is. How to modify the script that I can manualy set the directory to read?

//Code with alphabetical order:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
$files = glob("*");
foreach ($files as $file)    // replace `while` with `foreach`
{
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'html')
    {   

        $patterns = array();
        $patterns[0] = '/_/';
        $patterns[1] = '/.html/';
        $patterns[2] = '/index/';
        $replacements = array();
        $replacements[2] = ' ';
        $replacements[1] = '';
        $replacements[0] = 'Strona główna';
        $wynik = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $file);

        $newVariable = str_replace("_", " ", $file);  
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.ucfirst($wynik).'</a></li>';
    }

}

closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I've been looking in google, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead of `opendir()`. Glob will sort the files unless told not to.

```
$files = glob("*");
foreach ($files as $file)    // replace `while` with `foreach`
{
  // the rest of your code

}
```

Comment: @Daniel Koczuła See my edit, you already have the whole directory in an array when you use `glob()` so you don't have to use `readdir()` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`sort(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the file information to an array, sort the array, then echo out the information using a loop including your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SplHeap`

```
foreach(new AlphabeticDir(__DIR__) as $file)
{
    //Play Some Ball
    echo $file->getPathName(),PHP_EOL;
}
```

Class

```
class AlphabeticDir extends SplHeap
{
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $files  = new FilesystemIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $this->insert($file);
        }
    }
    public function compare($b,$a)
    {
        return strcmp($a->getRealpath(), $b->getRealpath());
    }
}
```